# Adding Multiple HTTPS Site on IIS 8.0

Tags: windows, iis-7.5, subdomain, iis-8

We are trying to add around 36000 domains in IIS 8.0. But when adding more than 2000 domains with 443 port and SSl cerficates, we are getting error. The Sites stop opening.

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

The application host config file size is 404 KB.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.